# In Hinduism Moksha is the name for eternal freedom. Is there a name for its opposite eternal bondage?

Tags: moksha

Moksha is eternal freedom, Is there such a place that is its opposite a place of eternal bondage? Man is the only vehicle to Moksha, is he also the only vehicle to eternal bondage if there is such a place?

Comment: One word will be Bandhana (bondage) but it is not eternal.

Comment: I thought of answering this question with a verse which defines the characteristics of Moksha and Bandhana in the same verse. But it was closed before I could do so. So I tried answering the other question.

Comment: @Rickross shame it was closed so quickly as questions are organic and many viewers no doubt would have enjoyed the verse. I just penned this re Bandhana and Atman. Within the all seeing eye I am and through the eyes of Prajapati I see, my breath moistens the soil of Prakriti and the seed for life called Bumi is born. I am Atman and I enter her womb and Bandhana begins.